# After restrating the Android Studio XML showing some encoded code with Android Studio 3.5.2

Tags: android, kotlin

After normal restart of android studio(with Version 3.5.2 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2), I am getting some unreadable code like

```
package com.myapp.android.Activity.Account;

import java.lang.System;

@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 15}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000@\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\u0010\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\b2\u0006\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\nH\u0002J\b\u0010\u000b\u001a\u00020\bH\u0002J\u0016\u0010\f\u001a\u00020\b2\f\u0010\r\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u000
```

I am getting above encoded code in XML file.
How to handle it?

Comment: Add full xml file here

Comment: Above is full xml

Comment: Isn't that the kotlin class?

Comment: Nope. Its an XML file.